# GTM create new variables in dependence to existing variable (WPForms tracking)

Tags: javascript, variables, google-tag-manager

I track the values of a WPForms form with GTM and with the following code I get the selected values from a multiselect dropdown:

```
  function() {
  var selectList = {{wpFormElement}}.querySelector('#wpforms-1397-field_16');
  var options = selectList ? selectList.options : [];
  var vals = [];
  var i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
      vals.push(options[i].value);
    }
  }
  return vals.length ? vals.join(' ') : undefined;
}
```

The output are the product-id's:

```
'2705 1446 2772'
```

I would like to submit the products with the real name to analytics and not the id. How do I get a new variable (each) with the real product name depending on the product-id's?

var1: 2705 = product 1

var2: 1446 = product 2

var3: 2772 = product 3

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need an array of product names.  The easiest way to go from one value to another is by using an object like the `productIdNameMap` variable in the example below.  This modified code will return a list of product names, so you can use a for loop to do something with each one if you want.

```js
(function() {
  var selectList = document.querySelector('#wpforms-1397-field_16');
  var options = selectList ? selectList.options : [];
  var productIdNameMap = {
    2705: 'product 1',
    1446: 'product 2',
    2772: 'product 3',
    2020: 'product 4'
  };

  var vals = [];
  var i, len, productId;
  for (i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
      productId = options[i].value
      vals.push(productIdNameMap[productId]);
    }
  }

  console.log(vals);
  return vals;
})();
```

```html
<select multiple id="wpforms-1397-field_16">
  <option selected>2705</option>
  <option selected>1446</option>
  <option selected>2772</option>
  <option>2020</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thx, that worked well. is there also a possibility to store the id's in an array instead of '2705 1446 2772' ?

Comment: You bet!  Just replace `vals.push(productIdNameMap[productId]);` with `vals.push(productId);` and that code will print an array of the ids.